# Getting 'Uncaught TypeError' when using coinslider

Tags: jquery, slider, typeerror

The full specific error is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #coin-slider has no method ‘coinslider’
```

I have looked into the problem pretty deeply, and it appears others have been plagued by this as well.

Unfortunately, the solutions that seem to have worked for them fail for me. Most of the people that have had this happen are, like me, pretty well newcomers to JQuery... so this may be simple, but will probably help numerous newbies like me.

My sample code is currently hosted at [techbuildersgroup.com/Sirah/](http://techbuildersgroup.com/Sirah)

That page will exist for as long as this problem does...Sorry the page is junk, it was really thrown together in gedit to get this working, first.

The most common answer that I have seen for this error relates to the load order of the scripts.

I was developing this locally, and was pulling in JQuery from Google, so when I checked the load order with the developer tools in Chrome, I noticed that despite the order the scripts were requested in code, JQuery was actually loading last.

Due to this, I built a local copy of JQuery, and made certain that the script calls are separated as widely as possible in the page.  JQuery is called in the head, while the coin-slider script is called at the bottom of the body.

This did not solve it.

Others that have had this issue have had their slider instantiation call messed up such that the browser was trying to call it immediately, before page ready.  Mine has always been wrapped in `$(document).ready(function(){...});`, so I don't understand if, why, or how that issue might apply to me.

Again, I am a newcomer to JQuery, and would *love* to be able to work with it more deeply.. it just seems that every time I dip my toes in, I get some kind of behavior that I can't explain at all...

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

=======================================================================

It has been requested that I post the code instead of hosting it offsite:

Relevant Code for head:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/coin-slider-styles.css">
  <!-- Import JQuery -->
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Relevant Code for Actual Slider (Sorry for any formatting issues in this section... was a bit of work to get it to display):

`<div id="image_scroller">`

```
  `<div id="coin-slider">`
     `<a href="#">`
        `<img src="img/sirah_logo.png">`
        `<span>sirah logo</span>`
     `</a>`
     `<a href="#">`
        `<img src="img/sirah_logo2.png">`
        `<span>sirah logo</span>`
     `</a>`
              ....
  `</div>`
```

`</div>`

And Relevant Script Calls:

```
  <!-- Instantiate Slider -->
  <script src="js/coin-slider.min.js"></script>
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function()
     {
        $("#coin-slider".coinslider());
     });
  </script>
```

I hope this helps, sorry for having hosted it first, rather than posting it.

Comment: Impossible to answer unless you show us some code. Failing that, please set up a JSFiddle.

Comment: Also make sure `jQuery` and `coinslider` is loaded via `script` and load order should be `jQuery` first and then `coinslider`.

Comment: OK... So having example code offsite is bad?  Sorry.  Will edit with code, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misplaced a closing bracket.

Change this

```
$("#coin-slider".coinslider());
```

To

```
$("#coin-slider").coinslider();
```

Comment: Thank you for picking up on that... 2 issues, here.

Comment: Thank you for picking up on that... 

That is corrected now... strangely, it is now working on the hosted side but still broken on the local side... with the exact same error?

Comment: AND THANK YOU!

Marked question as answered... not caring so much about local as remote anyway, just confused.

Wish I could rank you up more than just giving you the answer.

You're a life saver... Cherry, even.